# Importing 'os modules' into Spyder interpereter (Anaconda) doesn't work

Tags: python, spyder

I'm reading and studying the book "Automate the boring stuff with Python". When using Spyder Anaconda, when I try to `import os` module, and try to run code `os.path.getsize(filepath)` it doesn't give me any output nor does it give me an error.

When I use the IDLE, and run the same code, it works. I imported modules before in Spyder to use `rand int` function and it worked. Now when I try to `import os` and use any function related to it, it doesn't work? How do I figure this out?

Comment: I think you're missing a `print` to print something to the console: `print(os.path.getsize(filepath))`

Comment: I forgot to mention I did include print, but doesn't work.